# Change "twocolumn" option to obtain right to left columns

Tags: macros, two-column, right-to-left, class-options

When using twocolumn option writing on paper start from left side then the right side, my wish is change twocolumn option to start  writing on paper from right side

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}

% change twocolumn option to start writing from right side

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't babel and XeLaTeX handle that sort of thing?

Comment: Yes in xelatex with bidi, my hope is to learn  a simple manner to change twocolumn macro without packages bidi or babel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turns out not to be two hard. You just need to patch `\@outputdblcol` so that it reverses the order of the two columns. Obviously this will not change anything else to be right-to-left.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}

% change twocolumn option to start writing from right side
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@outputdblcol}
  {\hb@xt@\textwidth{%
     \hb@xt@\columnwidth{\box\@leftcolumn \hss}%
     \hfil
     {\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}%
     \hfil
     \hb@xt@\columnwidth{\box\@outputbox \hss}}}
  {\hb@xt@\textwidth{%
     \hb@xt@\columnwidth{\box\@outputbox \hss}%
     \hfil
     {\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}%
     \hfil
     \hb@xt@\columnwidth{\box\@leftcolumn \hss}}}
   {\message{Patching \string\@ouputdblcol\space succeded^^J}}
   {\message{Patching \string\@ouputdblcol\space failed^^J}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4] 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is more complicated than your proposed solution. For instance, if you have a `\section` in your first column and another one in the second column, then the order of toc will be wrong. See the `bidi` package to find out how it should be done properly.

Comment: @user118241 This doesn't surprise me. I would just `bidi` and be done with it. Feel free to post a better solution. But my guess is that the OP doesn't want to use `xelatex`. Presumably quite a lot of `bidi` needs to be replicated to do things properly.